# Does firebase put multiple cloud functions in one container? Or each container for different functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need to deploy firebase cloud functions in NodeJs 10. From the pricing plan, it says in this
[FAQ link](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#functions-runtime):

> **Why will I need a billing account to use the Node.js 10 runtime for
> Cloud Functions for Firebase?**
>
> Because of updates to its underlying architecture planned for August
> 17, 2020, Cloud Functions for Firebase will rely on some additional
> paid Google services: Cloud Build, Container Registry, and Cloud Storage. These architecture updates will apply for functions deployed
> to the Node.js 10 runtime. Usage of these services will be billed in addition to existing pricing.
>
> In the new architecture, Cloud Build supports the deployment of
> functions. You'll be billed only for the computing time required to
> build a function's runtime container.
>
> Cloud Storage, interoperating with Google Container Registry, will
> provide storage space for the containers in which functions run.
> You'll be billed for each container required to deploy a function. If
> you're currently using Cloud Functions within free usage limits, you
> may notice new, small charges for each container stored— for example,
> 1GB of storage is billed at $0.026 per month.
>
> To understand more about how your bill might change, please review the
> following
>
> - Cloud Functions pricing: existing free tier is unchanged.
> - Cloud Build pricing: Cloud Build provides for a free tier.
> - Container Registry pricing.

What I'd like to know is, are these containers restricted to one function? Or all of my functions can use them if their collective memory usages are below the container size?

Answer (score 2):

Each of your function will be deployed separately, regardless of how much memory they use. So that means one container will host one function only

Comment: So for every function $0.026 in container cost? (or according to however amount allocated)

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan that's not the case, atleast for me. I have around 30 functions running and it cost me 0.02$ last month. Mind you my usage is well within free limit

Comment: oh, so if I allocate the lowest amount of memory for a function, I can clear the cost entirely?